# PHP - Decoding user agent WITHOUT get_browser

Tags: php, user-agent

I have a site which allows my customers to setup content for their customers, I'm currently capturing stats using just date/time, ip and user agent.

I was going to process the statistics into another table (or additional columns) using `get_browser()` but my useless host has disabled this functionality.

I've spoken to the host and they say no to turning this on, I'd rather not switch hosts if possible.

I am looking for a way to process the user agent strings to give useful information but I don't want to hard-code too much.
I have tried using a large `preg_match()` list but it's getting too complex.

Is there any other method for decoding the user agent I can use without the `browscap.ini` file?

Alternatively could the statistics be shipped out to a third party (eg Google Analytics) but on a 'per customer' basis, so I can break down the usage by customer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using this class http://chrisschuld.com/projects/browser-php-detecting-a-users-browser-from-php/ in my project and it's working really well.

Comment: That looks very useful, do you know if it's easily update-able (via xml/text file)?

Comment: I think you'll need to download new file when updated (just add rss to your reader). When I needed support for some browsers just added them to the code.